# Azure continuous build is failing with "Unable to initialize blade from definition"

Tags: git, azure, build, continuous-integration

I have created a team project in azure, setup Git repo and published a new project into Azure, but I am having an issue with continuous build. I enabled build configuration from VS and set solution, platform and configuration to build my basic WebAPI project. However, I keep getting an error about the blade definition. Google searches have found no references to what this may mean and how to get around this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also got this when trying to create a Marketplace Hortonworks distribution (Std), not sure why.

Comment: I keep getting the same error when trying to setup a new sql server and database on my msdn azure subscription... Not sure what's going on. It worked ok last night.

Comment: Same here. Started happening over two hours ago

Comment: This is a year old issue; has it been addresses? The blades are part of the portal UI and these sorts of bugs are addressed pretty regularly... the JavaScript console can help provide more information, too.